# How can I Use Alpha Extension For All Object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have below code for changing the value of object like text,image , ... with Effect. and it work:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.lblCityTemp.alpha = 0.0
                        self.imgCityIcon.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: {
                        (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                        //Once the label is completely invisible, set the text and fade it back in
                        self.imgCityIcon.image = UIImage(named: icon)
                        self.lblCityTemp.text = "\(temp)°"

                        // Fade in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                            self.lblCityTemp.alpha = 1.0
                            self.imgCityIcon.alpha = 1.0

                        }, completion: nil)
                    })
```

Now I want make a extension of this code that I use for all my object that I write below code:

```
extension NSObject {

    func Fade (alphaOUT: Double,alphaIN: Double, input: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = CGFloat(alphaOUT)
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in

            // Fade in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.alpha = CGFloat(alphaIN)

            }, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

But I have error on self word and I do not know how can I set value for every object like label, imageView , ....

How can I do this?
Is the extension is best way or no?
If no, so what is the best way?

Comment: `NSObject` doesn't have an `alpha` property. `UILabel`, `UIImageView` do. You might want to add this extension to `UIView` which is a parent for `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea should be take some `UIView` and animate it. Then you need extension of `UIView` since this class has properties that you need to.

```
extension UIView { ... }
```

Anyway, what now if you need to do something when animation ends? Then you'll need **completion handler** parameter for your method

```
func fade(..., completion: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {
```

... which will be called after the first animation ends.

Next suggestions:

- You can say that alpha parameters should be of type `CGFloat`, then you don’t have to convert `Double` to `CGFloat`
- Also, what is `input`? I think you won't need it with this solution
- Method name should start with small capital letter and for naming parameters you should use camelCase

---

```
extension UIView {
    func fade(alphaOut: CGFloat, alphaIn: CGFloat, completion: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = alphaOut
        }, completion: { _ in
            completion() // this is called when animation ends
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.alpha = alphaIn
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Then when you need to call it, change what you need after animation ends in `completion` closure

```
imgCityIcon.fade(alphaOut: ___, alphaIn: ___) {
    self.imgCityIcon.image = UIImage(named: icon)
}
```

---

Note that you're using old syntax for some stuff:

For example `UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn` has been renamed to `UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn`. I would suggest you to start using newer versions of Swift

Comment: Thank You very Much. it is best way.      @Robert Dresler

Comment: You could save yourself the `CGFloat(alphaOut)` and put `alphaOut: CGFloat` directly instead (same for `alphaIn` of course).

Comment: @LinusGeffarth thanks for good suggestions with parameters' types and with default value for `completion` parameter

Comment: You're welcome. In my projects, I just don't like *having* to provide one, where I sometimes don't care about the completion.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to implement an extension for `UIView` instead of NSObject.
>   since NSObject doesn't have any property like alpha you will get an
>   error.

**Coding Example:**

```
extension UIView {
    func Fade (alphaOUT: Double,alphaIN: Double, input: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = CGFloat(alphaOUT)
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in

            // Fade in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.alpha = CGFloat(alphaIN)

            }, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}

class AnimationHelper {

class func Fade (alphaOUT: Double,alphaIN: Double, input: Any , yourLabel: UILabel, yourTextField: UITextField) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                yourLabel.alpha = CGFloat(alphaOUT)
                yourTextField.alpha = CGFloat(alphaOUT)
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                // Fade in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    // Access your text field and label here.

                }, completion: nil)
            })
        }

}
```

Comment: ok, so how can i send value for label.text or imageview.image like my question??

Comment: in your extension you didn't mention it

Comment: @MohammadHasanpoor for that I will suggest you not use extension since every time you might have different things to update. so it's better to create one method and do in it.

Comment: or you can use a hack by creating a helper method. and passing these label and text field to it.

Comment: how can i do that with method? (sorry i am begginer)

Comment: just copy the extension method and add it into your UIViewController class and use the alpha property of each view or just create helper method and pass your label and text field there. updating code for helper method.

Comment: I think you need to pass the parameters for whichever view's you want to animate. I hope it will help you to solve problem

Comment: Thank You very Much.  @ Jarvis The Avenger